# How to add index to CitusDB's cstore_fdw?

Tags: postgresql, indexing, olap, citus

I'm currently building an OLAP database in postgres and want to compare the performance of a column-store vs row-store database.  [CitusDB](http://citusdata.com/) open-sourced its columnar-store extension [cstore_fdw](https://github.com/citusdata/cstore_fdw) so I'm comparing database performance with and without this extension.

The [example](https://github.com/citusdata/cstore_fdw#example) shows how to make a test db and query it.  I have that example running.  But then I try to add indices to it to and get the error `ERROR:  cannot create index on foreign table "table_name"`.  It makes sense that I can't add indices to a foreign table.  Yet, I still need to index that table, or else there's no way it will do well slicing or drilling into the data.  How do I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

cstore_fdw currently doesn't support PostgreSQL indexes. But it automatically stores some min/max statistics in skip indexes which makes execution of some queries much more efficient.

To learn more about how to use skip indexes please consult [documentation](https://github.com/citusdata/cstore_fdw#using-skip-indexes).

Comment: Calling that documentation is a bit of a stretch. Not a lot of examples, no tips for optimization, nothing about what cstore_fdw can't do (that you might expect).